# REST webservice using Spring MVC returning null while posting JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, curl

Developing a REST web service using Spring MVC which accepts a JSON request body.
And process the received message further.
Iam using following : 
Eclipse, Tomcat, Spring 3.0.1, Jackson lib, Curl for testing the web service

```
    `curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d '{"fname":"my_firstname" , "lname":"my_lastname"}' http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/restful`
```

returning

```
"Saved person: null null"
```

My controller class

```
        import com.samples.spring.Person;

    @Controller
    public class RestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="{person}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
        public String savePerson(Person person) {
             // save person in database
            return "Saved person: " + person.getFname() +" "+ person.getLname();
        }
```

My person class

```
       package com.samples.spring;

    public class Person {

        public String fname;
        public String lname;

        public String getFname() {
            return fname;
        }
        public void setFname(String fname) {
            this.fname = fname;
        }
        public String getLname() {
            return lname;
        }
        public void setLname(String lname) {
            this.lname = lname;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Solved. Did two things as follows: 1.)Added @RequestBody 2.)Changed the Curl's JSON parameters from -d '{"fname":"my_firstname" , "lname":"my_lastname"}' ---- -d "{"""fname""":"""my_firstname""" , """lname""":"""my_lastname"""}". Can anyone explain this ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to add @RequestBody

```
@RequestMapping(value="{person}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
    public String savePerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
         // save person in database
        return "Saved person: " + person.getFname() +" "+ person.getLname();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add a constructor your Person class:

```
public Person(String fname, String lname) {
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
}
```