# Spring rest json post null values

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have a Spring rest endpoint doing a simple hello app. It should accept a {"name":"something"} and return "Hello, something".

My controller is:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController { 

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String greeting(Person person) {
        return String.format(template, person.getName());
    }

}
```

Person:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person() {
        this.name = "World";
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When I make a request to the service like

```
curl -X POST -d '{"name": "something"}' http://localhost:8081/testapp/greeting
```

I get

```
Hello, World!
```

Looks like it isn't deserializing the json into the Person object properly. It's using the default constructor and then not setting the name. I found this: [How to create a POST request in REST to accept a JSON input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417115/how-to-create-a-post-request-in-rest-to-accept-a-json-input) so I tried adding an @RequestBody on the controller but that causes some error about "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported". I see that is covered here: [Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported for @RequestBody MultiValueMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796218/content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencodedcharset-utf-8-not-supported-for) which suggests removing the @RequestBody

I have tried removing the default constructor which it doesn't like either.

This question covers null values [REST webservice using Spring MVC returning null while posting JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315662/rest-webservice-using-spring-mvc-returning-null-while-posting-json) but it suggests adding @RequestBody but that conflicts with above...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must set the `@RequestBody` to tell to Spring what should be use to set your `person`param.

```
 public Greeting greeting(@RequestBody Person person) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, person.getName()));
}
```

Comment: As I said in my description, that results in a "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported"

Comment: Your Content type should be `Content type 'application/json`

Comment: You might use PostMan or some other Json client to test your app, i might be easier.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, it's just not the expected Content Type

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with that content-type?

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't disable the controls, you should send the good information to your app. By the way if you prefer disable the controls try @PranayKumbhalkar advise.

Comment: The point is, there are already clients sending stuff to the old version that use that content-type. I need to be able to handle them until they get upgraded. And using the ALL_VALUE thing doesn't work anyway.

Comment: `ALL_VALUE` will not work, because your old sender is sending Json data  without telling the receiver it's Json ; so the receiver will not know how to process the data because the declarated data type (I.e.:Content-Type) is not corresponding to the data convey.

Comment: @RequestBody also worked for me. earlier i was getting null values in the object parrameters

Answer (score 0):

You must set '**produces**' with **@RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST)**

use below code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
 public String greeting(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return String.format(template, person.getName());
    }
```

Comment: "produces" refers to the response. The response is fine. Also, since it's returning a plain string, it should be MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE

Comment: try 'consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE'

Comment: @PranayKumbhalkar, `consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE` isn't a solution. If you can't pass through an check, the solution isn't disabling the check ; the solution is changing what you're sending.