# Spring POST receives object with null values

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I have an AngularJS web application that looks like it is correctly sending JSON to the Tomcat server, but the server receives null values. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935912/requestbody-is-getting-null-values) didn't help because my property names are already lowercase, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373421/spring-rest-json-post-null-values) didn't help because I've already got the `@RequestBody` notation. **Edit: as pointed out in the comments, I don't actually have this notation. I was reading it wrong.**

Here is the server method in question:

```
@PostMapping(path="/kind/add")
public @ResponseBody String addNewKind(Kind kind) throws Exception {
    if (kind.getName() == null) {
        throw new Exception("Name not found.");
    }
    kindRepository.save(kind);
    return "Saved";
}
```

Here is the Kind object it expects to receive:

```
@Entity
public class Kind {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="kind")
    private Set<Card> cards;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Card> getCards() {
        return cards;
    }

    public void setCards(Set<Card> cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }
}
```

Here is the method that makes the request:

```js
var uri = 'http://localhost:8080/catalog/api/kind/';

function create(name) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var data = {
        'name': name
    };
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: uri + 'add',
        data: angular.toJson(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error while adding kind');
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

This is the JSON sent to the server:

```
{"name":"Something"}
```

**N.B.** I assumed that I can get away without sending `id` or `cards` parameters, since `id` is auto-generated and `cards` can be empty; however, I get the same null results when sending the following JSON:

```
{"id":0,"name":"Something","cards":[]}
```

These are the request headers:

```
Accept:           application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:  en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection:       keep-alive
Content-Length:   20
Content-Type:     application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:            __distillery=08c4ef1_752470a4-…ID=lr9remoqoi0ht13v1urq5lq8r7
Host:             localhost:8080
Referer:          http://localhost:8080/catalog/
User-Agent:       Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0
```

And this is what the server receives when I view the `kind` object argument in debug mode:

```
kind= Kind
    cards= null
    id= 0
    name= null
```

Comment: _"..., because I've already got the @RequestBody notation"_ - Where? I only see the `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: @helospark You're right, how embarrassing! I was looking at `@RequestBody` and reading `@ResponseBody`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [@RequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) annotation on your method. Your controller doesn't know what the body is, so your posted object is never bound (or never "makes it") to your method's Kind parameter.

```
@PostMapping(path="/kind/add")
public String addNewKind(@RequestBody Kind kind) throws Exception {
    if (kind.getName() == null) {
        throw new Exception("Name not found.");
    }
    kindRepository.save(kind);
    return "Saved";
}
```

If you are expecting the new 'Kind' to be returned, you'd want your controller method to look like this:

```
@PostMapping(path="/kind/add")
public Kind addNewKind(@RequestBody Kind kind) throws Exception {
    if (kind.getName() == null) {
        throw new Exception("Name not found.");
    }
    return kindRepository.save(kind);
}
```

On a side note, I notice you are using single quotes in your JSON when you write it out. Since you are converting data with `angular.toJson()`, you should be OK there. If you are trying to interact by sending a JSON string directly, this will generally not work. JSON doesn't use single quotes.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the JSON above so it's not confusing to anyone reading the question in the future.