# Spring PostMapping receive object with null values

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm writing a SPRING controller to manage some entities, i've trouble when try to edit existing object.

Here is my get/post mapping that generate problems:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/category/{id}/edit")
public String editCategoryGET(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
    Category category = repositoriesServices.getCategoryById(id);
    log.info("editCategoryGET: " + category);
    // set model attribute etc....
}

@PostMapping(value = "/category/{id}/edit")
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity editCategoryPOST(@PathVariable int id, Category category) {
    log.info("editCategoryPOST: " + category);
    // code...
}
```

Category class is this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @Lob
    private String imageBase64;

    @Transient
    private MultipartFile image;

    // getter setter
}
```

When I try to edit a `Category` object, it comes right from DB as you can see in the log bottom, but when it come from `POST` the `imageBase64` field is `null`.

```
editCategoryGET: Category{id=1, name='vdsvsdv', imageBase64='data:image/png;base6...'}
editCategoryPOST: Category{id=1, name='vdsvsdv', imageBase64='null'}
```

The ajax `POST` call is done in this way:

```
var form = $('#form');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: form.attr("action"),
    data: new FormData(form[0]),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(.........
```

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618559/spring-post-receives-object-with-null-values), but if I put `@RequestBody` I get this error:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryZJlpA2NOKy6YhELW;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

even if I put `consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE` attribute.

I know that I can solve with another call to DB to get the old data, but I hope there is a cleanest method

**SOLUTION:**
I've solved sending json data after edit:

```
function getFormDataAsJSON() {
    var json = {};
    json.name = $('#name-input').val();
    json.imageBase64 = $('#logo-preview').attr('src');
    return json;
}


var form = $('#form');
var postData = {};
postData.formData = new FormData(form[0]);
var flag = false;
if ($('#div-visible-only-in-edit-way').length !== 0) {
    flag = true;
    postData.jsonData = getFormDataAsJSON();
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: form.attr("action"),
    data: flag ? JSON.stringify(postData.jsonData) : postData.formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: flag ? "application/json; charset=utf-8" : false,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (e) {
```

Comment: When you add @RequestBody you are expecting json data but sending form data from client. Change your javascript code to sending json data.

Comment: I've solved with your comment, if you put it as answer I'll accept as correct

Comment: I glad to it helps, added comment to help it others too. Also I suggest you to edit your answer with valid request.

Comment: I've already done, thank you so much again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add @RequestBody you are expecting json data but sending form data from client.

You should change your javascript code to send json request.