# Json recieved from frontend become "null" in backend

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, backend

I designed a controller that receives a Json from frontend.
The controller is called properly.
When I print the elements of that Json to console, they become "null".

The frontend sends the json `{'username':"abc", "password":123 }` to backend. 
The controller is called properly but the values of 'username' and 'password' become null when I print them to console.

The Json sent from frontend `{'username':'abc', 'password':12345 }`. 
The request url of frontend is `http://my_ip_address:port/login/`

Here is my code of Controller:

```
@RestController 
@CrossOrigin("*") 
@RequestMapping( value="login", produces="application/json" ) 
public class LoginController{ 

    @PostMapping(value="/", consumes="application/json") 
    @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK ) 
    public void SignIn( Members member ){ 

        System.out.println("username:"+member.getUsername() + 
                           "\npassword: "+member.getPasssword() ); 
        // The values of Json become null!!!.

    } 
}
```

Here is my Members:

```
public class Members{ 
    private String username; 
    private String password; 

    /* omit setters and getters */ 
}
```

I have tried to add @RequestBody to the method but it turns out to be 
`Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing.`

I am confused by the results. 
In fact, I got the expected result at the first time. 
But when I restarted the project again, it becomes so weird.

## UPDATE.

### Problem fixed.

- Add @RequestBody to the method.
- The problem is that I forgot to put the data into body of HTTP request. It passed "null" values to backend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring rest json post null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373421/spring-rest-json-post-null-values)

Comment: And you checked the network tabs in your dev tools to 100% confirm that correct JSON is being sent?

Comment: Yes, I definitely sure that the JSON is sent.

Comment: The truth is the JSON is not 100% correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `@RequestBody`:

```
@PostMapping(value="/", consumes="application/json") 
@ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK ) 
public void SignIn(@RequestBody Members member ){ 

    System.out.println("username:"+member.getUsername() + 
                       "\npassword: "+member.getPasssword() ); 
    // The values of Json become null!!!.

}
```

It turns out that you do not need to use `consumes` attribute. It comes as default.

Comment: Yes, I tried it before. 
But the console returns ```Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing. ```

Comment: Were you able to make a request via POSTMAN?

Comment: I just used POSTMAN to make a request. The result of the response is still ```{"username":null,"password":null}```.